# How do I pick a string from a list and put it in a new list with the criteria

Tags: python, string, list

Basically my question is-
Im not sure how to take a list of foods:

```
foods=['Steak','French Fries','Hamburger','Spinach Pasta','Omelette','beans','Chicken']
```

and returns
        veggies - Food objects from foods that are vegetarian (list of Food)

the problem is im not sure if Im supposed to make a new list and add the vegetarian food from the "foods" list to the new one or if the word "objects" has anything to do with this

also how would I be able to go through the list to check to see if it is a veg or not a veg?

this is an assignment that I have to do so I dont want any code answers please but if someone could explain so I could learn for future references that would be amazing

hopefully my question makes sense and that I am allowed to ask this type of question, thanks in advance :)

Comment: First of all, what are you trying to do?  Do you have a list of vegetarian foods you can check against?  Or is this some kind of object-oriented exercise where you have to think about classifications of things?

Comment: Initially I have to create a list which I did, but then from the list I am supposed to find out what is veg and what is not veg and the main question is how do i do that, I figure you use the append function but idk how to  check if it is veg from the list

Comment: Use a `dictionary` instead, then you can put your items in categories within it.

Comment: def get_vegetarian(foods):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Creates a list of vegetarian foods.
    Use: v = get_vegetarian(foods)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Preconditions:
        foods - a list of Food objects (list of Food)
    Postconditions:
        returns
        veggies - Food objects from foods that are vegetarian (list of Food)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """

((((((hopefully you guys can read that properly but thats all the question gives me))))))

Comment: Somewhere you need labelled data to know what a "vegetarian" food is.  The suggestion of using a [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) would allow for quick look up of classification, but you'd have to know how to classify it.  From your samples, this seems like an object-oriented exercise to think about inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict)

You can create a dictionary like this:

```
foods = { "Steak": "not-veg", "Spinach Pasta": "veg" }
```

And you can check if Steak is vegetarian food like this:

```
if foods["Steak"] == "veg":
    print("Vegetarian food")
else:
    print("Not a vegetarian food")
```

This is a very naive approach. You can store boolean values in dictionary or define a check function which accepts the food name and return or print the result or you can even build a class which have a is_vegetarian method.